# display Hex in cmd

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have some trouble with batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set LOOKUP=0123456789abcdef &set HEXSTR= 

set MAC_B1=03
set MAC_B2=5D
set MAC_B3=00
set MAC_B4=00
set MAC_B5=00
set MAC_B6=00
set my_file=runningno.txt

set runningno=128

setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set LOOKUP=0123456789abcdef &set /a HEXSTR= 

set /a A=%runningno%

:loop
set /a B=!A! %% 16 & set /a A=!A! / 16
set HEXSTR=!LOOKUP:~%B%,1!%HEXSTR%
if %A% GTR 0 goto :loop
if %runningno% LEQ 255 (
set /a MAC_B6 = %HEXSTR%
)

ECHO MAC address:%MAC_B1%-%MAC_B2%-%MAC_B3%-%MAC_B4%-%MAC_B5%-%MAC_B6%
```

the output is fine if i get runningno in hex without "abcdef"

```
03-5D-00-00-00-80
```

in other i.e set `runningno=255` the output should be `03-5D-00-00-00-FF` but is

```
03-5D-00-00-00-0
```

PLEASE HELP

Comment: What does your code do? I feel like I'm missing something important...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "mac_b1=03"
    set "mac_b2=5d"
    set "mac_b3=00"
    set "mac_b4=00"
    set "mac_b5=00"
    set "mac_b6=00"

    set "runningno=128"

    set "lookup=0123456789abcdef"
    set /a "high=(runningno & 255) >> 4", "low=runningno & 15"
    set "mac_b6=!lookup:~%high%,1!!lookup:~%low%,1!"

    echo %mac_b1%-%mac_b2%-%mac_b3%-%mac_b4%-%mac_b5%-%mac_b6%
```

**edited** As it seems the value in the `runningno` will increase,

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    set "mac_b1=03"
    set "mac_b2=5d"
    set "mac_b3=00"
    set "mac_b4=00"
    set "mac_b5=00"
    set "mac_b6=00"

    set "runningno=1458796"

    set "lookup=0123456789abcdef"

    set "value=%runningno%"
    for /l %%a in (6, -1, 3) do (
        set /a "high=(value & 255) >> 4", "low=value & 15", "value>>=8"
        for %%H in (!high!) do for %%L in (!low!) do (
            set "mac_b%%a=!lookup:~%%H,1!!lookup:~%%L,1!"
        )
    )

    echo %mac_b1%-%mac_b2%-%mac_b3%-%mac_b4%-%mac_b5%-%mac_b6%
```

BUT this has a problem. Arithmetics in batch files are limited to 32bit signed integers. That means that the higher value that can be handled with this method is `0x7fffff`

Comment: can you explain me this one ??    set /a "high=(runningno & 255) >> 4", "low=runningno & 15"
    set "mac_b6=!lookup:~%high%,1!!lookup:~%low%,1!"

Comment: @BartJ4F, a number in the range 0-255 has 8 bits, 4 high, 4 low. `x & 255` is a bitwise `AND` operation that ensures the number is in the rante 0-255. `x >> 4` is shift the bits 4 position to the right, so the 4 lower bits are moved out and the four upper bits are now low. `x & 15` cleans the four upper bits leaving only the four lower.

Comment: @BartJ4F, a substring operation is in the form `%var:~start,length%` with start and length digits. But as we need to use a variable *inside* the operation (as the start), we need delayed expansion syntax on the lookup variable, so it becomes `!var:~%start%,length!`

Comment: ok so what if the Runningno will be higer than 255 and I will want to set another mac_b5 ??and so on ??

Comment: @BartJ4F, answer updated, BUT note the limitation in batch artihmetic. I'm not sure what you are trying to do, maybe the approach of only an increasing counter is not the most adecuated.